# Make access to remote shell via local unix socket via http connection

Tags: shell, nginx, websocket, lua, socat

I need to have shell access to remote host by my server unix-socket through http connection initiated by remote host.

I know how it can be possible by straight forward manner without http:

1. Server listen TCP-PORT and maps it to UNIX-SOCKET:

`server# socat TCP-LISTEN:12345 UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/12345.sock`

2. Remote host maps Shell to the initiated TCP connection:

`remote# socat EXEC:sh,pty,stderr,setsid,sigint,sane TCP:my.server.com:12345`

3. To connect remote shell I can do this:

`` server# socat FILE:`tty`,raw,echo=0 UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/12345.sock ``

Schema of the 3 steps above:

> **remote** [shell] -> tcp:my.server.com:12345 :: **server** :: unix:/tmp/12345.sock <- **server** [tty]

Next I need to have HTTPS between **remote** and **server**. What would step 1 do the server on http Request. So I want to have schema like this:

> **remote** [shell] -> **https**://my.server.com:443/**shell** :: **server** [*open unix:/tmp/12345.sock on Request **/shell***] :: unix:/tmp/12345.sock <- **server** [tty]

I use ngnix and as I know LUA can be working inside it. But I don't have enough knowledge of LUA to implement the plan.

**UPD 2020.02.12**

I found websocket have to be used. So the Schema looks like this:

> remote [shell] -> **WebSocket proxy Client** -> https://my.server.com:443/shell :: Web Server -> **WebSocket Server** [starts listen unix:/tmp/12345.sock] :: unix:/tmp/12345.sock <- server [tty]

How **WebSocket proxy Client** and **WebSocket Server** can be made?